# Wine on YoiTV works on VM but not on metal?

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, wine

I've tried making the [`.exe` version of YoiTV (it's the MediaFire link)](https://livejapanesetv.wordpress.com/yoitv-free-key-codes/) work on an Archcraft VM via Wine and it worked perfectly, but now that I've installed Archcraft on my dual-boot machine (with Windows), it isn't working (they are both the same, latest ISO). What gives?

> I'm not experience with Wine at all, so sorry if this ends up being an easy fix...

The installer does work stilland this is Wine's output on the terminal

```
   YOITV1.0.0.2   git:(master) wine YoiTV_1.0.0.2.exe.exe
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
010c:fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
010c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (00010086, 1): stub
010c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001008E, 00010086): stub
010c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (0001008E): stub
010c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonCreate (0001008E, L"Installing"): stub
00a0:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0000000000010026, 0): stub
00a0:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0000000000010020, 0000000000010026): stub
010c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmStartSession 0050D010, 0, 0050D014 stub!
010c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (0001008E): stub
010c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonCreate (0001008E, L"Installing YoiTV."): stub
010c:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0002009C c04f 1 00000000
010c:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0003009C c04f 1 00000000
010c:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 000100A8 c04f 1 00000000
010c:fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 000200A8 c04f 1 00000000
010c:fixme:shell:SHAutoComplete stub
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C8 enable 0: stub!
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C8 enable -1: stub!
```

And this is what pops up when I finish the install and try to run it:

```
010c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmRegisterResources -559038737, 47, 023D4940, 0, 00000000, 0, 00000000 stub!
010c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmGetList -559038737, 0062F234, 0062F238, 023D4940, 0062F230 stub!
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C6 enable 0: stub!
010c:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetProgressValue iface 017B06E0, hwnd 0001008E, ullCompleted 0, ullTotal 3a6 stub!
010c:fixme:sfc:SfcIsFileProtected (00000000, L"C:\\users\\philippe\\AppData\\Local\\YoiTV\\unins000.exe") stub
010c:fixme:explorerframe:taskbar_list_SetProgressState iface 017B06E0, hwnd 0001008E, flags 0 stub!
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C6 enable -1: stub!
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C8 enable 0: stub!
010c:fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hwnd 000100C8 enable -1: stub!
012c:err:winediag:gnutls_process_attach failed to load libgnutls, no support for encryption
012c:err:winediag:process_attach failed to load libgnutls, no support for pfx import/export
012c:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (00D7FDC0 1 C) semi-stub
012c:fixme:toolhelp:CreateToolhelp32Snapshot Unimplemented: heap list snapshot
012c:fixme:toolhelp:Heap32ListFirst : stub
012c:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:bcrypt:key_asymmetric_create no encryption support
012c:err:mmdevapi:DllGetClassObject Driver initialization failed
012c:err:ole:apartment_getclassobject DllGetClassObject returned error 0x80004005 for dll L"C:\\windows\\system32\\mmdevapi.dll"
012c:err:ole:com_get_class_object no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1
010c:fixme:rstrtmgr:RmEndSession 3735928559 stub!
010c:fixme:graphics:ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy (0001008E): stub
```

After this failure, both `.desktop` and `.lnk` files are created on my Desktop, but none of them do anything.

> I've added [this to the Wine Forums](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=36896).

Answer (score 0):

[As discussed in the Wine Forums](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=36896), I needed to install 3 extra packages, since YoiTV seems to be a 32-bit application:

- `lib32-gnutls`
- `lib32-alsa-lib`
- `lib32-libpulse`